# Como puedo solucionar el error de mapeo de clases, estoy usando AutoMapper y MediatR

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq

Siempre que llamo al controlador para que me muestre la lista de docentes con sus grados académicos me marca este error, la verdad no se como poder solucionarlo ya lo revise y no puedo encontrar el detalle del error, para ser un poco mas especifico los modelos, las clases Dto, la logica los tengo separados en librerías de clases

```
"errores": "Error mapping types.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nList`1 -> List`1\r\nSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Software.Modelos.Docente, Software.Modelos, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Software.TransferenciaDto.Docentes.DocenteDto, Software.TransferenciaDto, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"
```

Esta es mi lógica para listar Docentes

```
namespace Software.Logica.Docentes{
    public class ManejadorListarDocente : IRequestHandler<ListarDocente, List<DocenteDto>>{
        private  readonly SistemaSpaContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public ManejadorListarDocente(SistemaSpaContext context, IMapper mapper) {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
        public async Task<List<DocenteDto>> Handle(ListarDocente request, CancellationToken cancellationToken){
            var docentes = await _context.Docente.Include(x => x.GradoAcademicoLink).ThenInclude(x => x.GradoAcademico).ToListAsync();
            var docenteDto = _mapper.Map<List<Docente>, List<DocenteDto>>(docentes);
            return docenteDto;
        }
    }
   
}
```

Esto es mi controlller

```
 public class DocentesController:  MiControllerBase
    {
        //GET: api/Docentes
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<DocenteDto>>> ListarDocentes()
        {
            return await Mediador.Send(new ListarDocente());
        }
        //POST: api/Docentes
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> CrearDocente(CrearDocente data)
        {
            return await Mediador.Send(data);
        }
        //GET: api/Docentes/{id}
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<DocenteDto>> ListarDocentesPorId(Guid id)
        {
            return await Mediador.Send(new ListarPorIdDocente {DocenteId = id });
        }
    }
```

Estos son mis modelos

```
public class Docente: Persona
    {
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public ICollection<FormacionAcademica> GradoAcademicoLink { get; set; }
        public ICollection<HabilidadesDocente> HabilidadLink { get; set; }
    }

public class Persona
    { 
        public Guid PersonaId { get; set; }
        public string Dni { get; set; }
        public string Nombres { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

public class FormacionAcademica
    {
        public Guid DocenteId { get; set; }
        public Guid GradoAcademicoId { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaEgresado { get; set; }

        public Docente Docente { get; set; }
        public GradoAcademico GradoAcademico { get; set; }
    }
 public class GradoAcademico
    {
        public Guid GradoAcademicoId { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public List<FormacionAcademica> DocenteLink { get; set; }
    }
```

Estas son mis clases DTO

```
public class PersonaDto
    {
        public Guid PersonaId { get; set; }
        public string Dni { get; set; }
        public string Nombres { get; set; }
        public string Apellidos { get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
 public class DocenteDto: PersonaDto
    {
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public ICollection<GradoAcademicoDto> GradosAcademicos { get; set; }
    }
public class FormacionAcademicoDto
    {
        public Guid DocenteId { get; set; }
        public Guid GradoAcademicoId { get; set; }
    }
 public class GradoAcademicoDto
    {
        public Guid GradoAcademicoId { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
    }
```

Esta es mi configuración para mapear las clases

```
public class MappingProfile: Profile{
        public MappingProfile(){
            CreateMap<Docente, DocenteDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.GradosAcademicos,
                y => y.MapFrom(x => x.GradoAcademicoLink.Select(x => x.GradoAcademico).ToList()));
                
            CreateMap<FormacionAcademica, FormacionAcademicoDto>();
            CreateMap<GradoAcademico, GradoAcademicoDto>();
            CreateMap<Persona, PersonaDto>();
        } 
    }
```

esta es la configuracion en Startup

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ManejadorListarDocente));
```

Esta es la cabecera para listar docentes

```
 public class ListarDocente : IRequest<List<DocenteDto>> { }
```

Comment: No veo donde tienes la configuración para el mapeo de las clases...

Comment: En tu Dto de grado académico no veo la lista de formación académica dto, pero cuando realizas el mapeo se espera esta lista, es esto correcto?